# How to submit form with action from other controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @category do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :parent_id, collection: @board.subtree, include_blank: false %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

`@category` is instance of `Board` so this `:submit` tries to run `create` action from `BoardsController`. Instead of it, I'd like to run `create` action from `CategoriesController`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `url` option.

```
<%= simple_form_for @category, url: category_path(@category) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136142/2128691

so yours would look like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @category, :url => category_path, do |f| %>
 ...
<% end
```

Comment: `method: :post` is the default. It makes no sense to add it here.

Comment: just modified from source - but you're right, no need for extra code.  will edit.