# dealing with select_tags in controller after a submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

Trying to figure out how to use section

3.2 Select Boxes for Dealing with Models 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

With my deeply nested models. (A provider can have a provider location, which is a join on provider id and  group locationid.  A group location is a group and an address).  This is the nesting of like how do I deal/consume the data thats in those select boxes once the user adds/removes locations that way.

[image]

This takes all the group locations and lists them and lets me add them to the current provider under proivder_locations.

Basically get what is working 'dumbly' on the controller side upon f.submit

Flow is:

User creates a provider, then the show it asks if they would like to add location to their newly created provider.
If so it takes them to add_location.html.erb file where they have two select boxes.  One with all the locations they can add and one 
that shows any current locations the provider already has.

I have the page handling displaying of the right locations and that and 
handling the form adding/deleting.   This is great, but the form_for breaks (see bottom) and even then I have no idea how to handle or deal with the data that is on the client side in these select tags.  Do I consume it in the controller somehow?  Again the section 3.2 talks about it but the part that really stumps me is it doesn't seem applicable to my models in their 3.2 section.

**(Side note, I had that f.form_for in there not really tested, without it the form works great in terms of buttons adding subtracting from the lists on the html side, with
it breaks when I click any of the buttons to add/remove things from lists)**
(error screen shot at bottom)

All the code:

Provider.rb

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    #validates :credentialing_contact, presence: true

    has_many :provider_locations
    has_many :group_locations, through: :provider_locations
    has_many :groups, through: :group_locations 
    belongs_to :designation
    belongs_to :specialty
    #has_many :provider_locations
    has_many :invoices
    has_many :provider_terms
end
```

provider_location.rb

```
class ProviderLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider  
  belongs_to :group_location

end
```

group_location.rb

```
class GroupLocation < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :provider_locations
end
```

providers_controller.rb

```
class ProvidersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_provider, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @providers = Provider.all
  end

  def show
    #@provider = Provider.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @provider=Provider.new

     respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: ghouse }
      end

  end

  def edit
  end

  def add_location
    @provider = Provider.find(params[:id])
    @group_locations = GroupLocation.all
    if @provider.nil?
      puts 'Error here!'
    end
    #throw an error if the provider is nil

  end

  def create
    @provider = Provider.new(provider_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @provider.save
            format.html { redirect_to @provider, notice: 'Provider was successfully created.'}
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @provider }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @provider.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /groups/1
  # PATCH/PUT /groups/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @provider.update(provider_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @provider, notice: 'provider was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @provider }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @provider.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /groups/1
  # DELETE /groups/1.json
  def destroy
    #@group = Group.find(params[:id])
    #if(@group.present?)
    #   @group.destroy
    #end
    @provider.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to providers_url, notice: 'provider was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_provider
      @provider = Provider.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def provider_params
      params.require(:provider).permit(:last_name, :first_name, :dob, :license_num, :license_exp, :dea_num, 
        :dea_exp, :ptan, :caqh_num, :provider_npi, :effective_date, :provisional_effective_date, :date_joined, 
        :provider_contact, :credentialing_contact, :hospitalaffiliation, :group_id, :specialty_id, :designation_id, :notes, :created_at, :updated_at)    
    end
end
```

(add_location.html.erb this is gotten to from the show controller)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for (@provider) do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>            
                  <h3> <%= @provider.last_name %> , <%= @provider.first_name %> 's Locations</h3>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                 <% if @provider.provider_locations.count >0 %>
                    <%= select_tag "provider_locations", options_from_collection_for_select(@provider.provider_locations.map{|j| j.group_location}, :id , :dba), :multiple => true %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= select_tag "provider_locations", "<option></option>".html_safe, :multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px" %>       
                  <% end %>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                   <button class="remove">Remove</button> 

                </td>
                <td>          
                  <button class="removeAll">Remove All</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>         
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <table>
              <tr>
                <th>            <!-- maybe some buttons here -->

                </th>
              </tr>                   
            </table>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>            
                 <h3> All Group Locations </h3> <!-- might need a search here too -->
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                  <% if @group_locations.count >0 %>
                    <%= select_tag "group_providers", options_from_collection_for_select(GroupLocation.all, :id , :dba), :multiple => true %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= select_tag "group_providers", "<option>Add new...</option>".html_safe, :multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px" %>       
                  <% end %>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                    <button class="add">Add</button>

                </td>
                <td>          
                    <button class="addAll">Add All</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>        
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second issue the form_for in general is breaking my code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the reason you're getting an error when you try to submit is because you're submission is trying to go to the update action (because your parameters '_method' is 'patch'). When it gets there it hits the line

`if @provider.update(provider_params)`

which directs it to your `provider_params` method. This method is designed to only let through certain parameters, mainly a provider and its associated information (denoted by the ':provider' symbol). Since that information isn't there it stops the submission and errors out. There are several ways you can fix this.

1. Have your form_for submit to a different controller action ([Routing form submission to a different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136126/routing-form-submission-to-a-different-controller))
2. Change your update action to support the lack of provider parameters

Personally I recommend the first option, though it is getting away for rails REST architecture.

As for handling the data, if I understand correctly you're trying to create the link between the provider and the group_location (i.e. a provider_location). Forgetting anything else that object might require it will certainly need

1. The provider's id
2. The group_location's id

Which I believe you already have coming through in your params, assuming 'id' refers to your provider's id and 'group_providers' is an array of the group_location ids (if it's not then you need to use the form_for to get that info in the parameter since you'll need it). Then it's as simple as looping through the group_location ids and creating a provider_location with the group_location id and the provider id.

```
params[:group_providers].each do |g_id|
   # using 'find_or_create_by' may be unnecessary but
   # can help avoid duplicate entries
   ProviderLocation.find_or_create_by(provider_id: params[:id].to_i, group_location_id: g_id.to_i)
end
```

Note: if the IDs that come through are meant to reflect the exact state of the provider_location (i.e. if when you submit you also want to delete provider_locations that currently exist but who's ids aren't included in the params) then the loop becomes significantly more complicated algorithmically so if that's what you're trying to do let me know and I'll try to help

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I think my associations always confuse me.  When you say I should have that in my parameter that means upon clicking update yes then it would be there (in the right controller action of course that I need to also fix based on your first part of response).   Secondly If I do have these ids in a param how do I connect them?  @provider.provider_location << group_id wouldn't work I think...I would have to first grab the object using that id (GroupLocation find) then assign it  using an array <<  add yes?  Lastly you are right they are to reflect the exact state...

Comment: ...if you remove from the provider locations then indeed the provider locations has to be updated upon clicking submit.  Also with the first part of your response pertaining to my error, I was confused because just clicking 'add' or something did a form submit, do all buttons by default submit?

Comment: To put it in terms of your web view when you click 'Add' or 'Add All' you want your program to send an array of GroupLocation id's with the other parameters to the appropriate controller action. In terms of connecting them, correct me if I'm wrong here, but to my understanding you're trying to connect Providers to GroupLocations. If this is the case that the ProviderLocations are the connection Ex: I have a provider with id=1 and a GroupLocation with id=1 and I want to connect them. I can do ProviderLocation.create(provider_id: 1, group_location_id: 1). Now if I call '.group_locations' on...

Comment: I actually envisioned it to say when I say add or add all it puts it to the other side in the select box.  Then when save/update is called then it saves what was on that other select box (the one on the left)  array out to @provider.provider_locations

Comment: that provider it will return an array of GroupLocations, including that one. Yes, all the buttons will submit but default since they're in a form_for, but you should be able to change where they each submit to in the controller and so you can handle them appropriately (I would probably send the removing to one controller action and the adding to another)

Comment: Ahhh do sending those to the controller would allow me to update the provider object without having to do it all at once.  How does the provider return an array of group locations is that the argument to select tag "provider_ location"  ?   That's the key in params it comes back as an array?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need some JavaScript to do that since it sounds like you want it to happen auto-synchronously. A a server side language the Ruby in your page is just displaying how it's associated in your database so to update the data on the page you'll need to update the database if you're just using vanilla Ruby on Rails

Comment: You are right.  So I can hold all the add removes let them update the select in the home page then upon actually clicking submit , then deal with the data in whatever parameter it comes across creating those provider locations on the fly in @provider.  More or less

Comment: No that's setup through your associations,  `has_many :group_locations, through: :provider_locations` in the Providers table in particular. Because of the way you have that set up you'll have a '.group_locations' method on any provider instance and a '.providers' method for and GroupLocation instance

Comment: Perhaps my associations are not right.  I was always using @provider.provider_locations to get an array of group locations.   Since it was a thorough

Comment: Oops lied about the second one, you'll need to add a `has_many :providers,  through: :provider_locations` to the GroupLocations model if you want the .providers method

Comment: using '@provider.provider_locations' would return an array of provider_locations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96744/discussion-between-codejoy-and-rocco-basso).